# Google API calls from amazon instances

Tags: php, api, amazon-ec2, google-api

Am using the amazon instances to call the google shortener URL API. whenever i calls the server it returns the below error

```
(
    [error] => stdClass Object
        (
            [errors] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [domain] => usageLimits
                            [reason] => rateLimitExceeded
                            [message] => Rate Limit Exceeded
                        )

            )

        [code] => 403
        [message] => Rate Limit Exceeded
    )

)
```

Please assist me to fix this issue.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: How are you making the call? Are you using a registered API Key? Have you signed up for the service?

Comment: Perhaps you should cache the responses, so you don't have to make the request for each pagevew?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error typically reflects a quota limit being exceeded, or a client sending too many unbatcheded requests at once. Unless you activate billing, your rate will be limited.